# Redirect after clicking an external link and only open one tab/window

Tags: javascript, jsp, cross-browser, window

I have created a jsp for external clients of my application to use to link to the web client. They can specify which client they are in the URL so that when the link opens a window it is named and any other links from that client will open in the same window. Here's an example URL:

> mysite.com/redirect.jsp?fromClient=mine&page=awesome

The problem is that when you click on this link, for example from an email digest, it opens the `redirect.jsp` page which uses `window.open()` to open the desired page. From the above link, the page that would open would be:

> mysite.com/index.jsp?page=awesome

So then I have two pages open, when really I only want one. And since I'm not using javascript to open the first page (it's a link), I can't use `window.close()` to close it. I've tried working around using `window.open('','_parent','')` and `window.open('','_self','')` but neither works.

I know there has to be a better way to redirect than to open a second window from my jsp page, but I don't know what that better way is. Thoughts?

**EDIT**
Primary goal is for users of external clients to be able to click links in that client and have all the links take them to the same window/tab in a browser. I'm using `window.open` right now because I can parse the link and get the client name and then supply that in the `window.open` function.

**EDIT 2**
I always end up being too vague in these questions. Ok, here's the setup:

An email digest contains a link that looks like

> mysite.com/redirect.jsp?fromClient=emailDigest&pageNum=4

Currently, when that link is clicked on, it opens a browser (duh) and then the `redirect.jsp` page parses that link to get the client name, in this case *emailDigest*. It then calls `window.open('mysite.com/index.jsp?pageNum=4','emailDigest')`. This creates a new window with the name `emailDigest` unless a window/tab with that name already exists, in which case it merely updates the URL in that window with the new one.

I want to either be able to close the original window (the one with the `redirect.jsp` address) or not have to open that initial window at all.

**NOTE**
As there are many different clients that want to be able to do this, I cannot guarantee that they will be creating the link with HTML so the `target` attribute is not the answer.

Comment: why `redirect.jsp` uses `window.open()`? it will make more sense if it will just redirect

Comment: Right, I'm looking for a way to redirect but still be able to name the window so that any other links that come in with the same `fromClient` value will open in the same window.

Comment: as I've understood you have 2 pages `redirect.jsp` and `index.jsp`. first one is being opened via `window.open()` right? and that's normal, but why the second one which should be just redirected from first one is also being opened via `window.open()`?

Comment: No. The first is not being opened with `window.open`, it's just a link. I'm currently using `window.open` for the second because you can pass in a name/title for the window so that you can reuse the same window with links from the same client.

Comment: ah ok :) so just use `window.open()` for the first one and set name to the window, then use a simple redirection on the second one without using `window.open()`

Comment: I can't because the first one is coming from links in email digests, buttons on desktop applications, and links in an Outlook client.

Comment: in this case you can't use the same window/tab in the browser if the link comes from different external clients, sorry for misunderstanding question at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is "No, it cannot be done". If you do not open a window with Javascript then you cannot close it with Javascript. I would always have to create at least 2 windows, which is not what we wanted.

Comment: Did you find a solution since all these years. I'm trying to achieve the same things... From my research, this still can’t be done without a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `window.location` instead of `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

As haynar says above, why do you open a window and not either:

```
<!-- content contains the refresh delay in seconds and the target url -->
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL="http://mysite.com/index.jsp?page=awesome">
```

or use javascript to do the same:

```
window.location.href = "http://mysite.com/index.jsp?page=awesome";
```

either works fine and will leave you with one window open.

To get the named window use a targeted link:

```
<a href="mysite.com/redirect.jsp?fromClient=mine&page=awesome" target="mine">Mysite.com</a>
```

This will automatically set the name property of the opened window.

Comment: You can give the window a title with `<title>my title</title>`. If you are referring to the name you provide when opening a separate window, you can do that inside the window as well. Just call `window.name = "myname";`.

Comment: I've been trying that, but it doesn't work. It's still opening new windows. I want it to find the already named window when the page is being created not re-assigning the name after it's already open.

Comment: Actually if you already open the redirect page with an anchor that has a target attribute, this attribute will be reused later on, so there is no need to set the name attribute again. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use window.location.replace("http://mysite.com/index.jsp?page=awesome");

> **Reason :**
>
> replace(url):Replace the current document with the one at the provided
>   URL. The difference from the assign() method is that after using
>   replace() the current page will not be saved in session history,
>   meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to
>   it.

Comment: I'll ask you the same question: can I assign a name/title to the window so that I can reuse it?